# Designing a game database

Tags: sql, database-design, mysql

I'm trying to design a database to record game histories for a game I'm working on. I have 3 different tables: users, gamehistories, and gamescores.

***Columns for tables:***

**users**: uid, displayname, email 
**gamehistories**: gid, pubID, start (datetime), end (datetime) 
**gamescores**: gid, uid, score

I am trying to produce the following result set given a userID (uid): 
Opponent's displayname, my score, opponent's score, duration

Any ideas? Is my design ok? How can I query these tables to get game histories for a given uid?

Comment: How many players can participate in a game simultaneously?  What is the purpose of pupID?

Comment: 2 players. pubID is the url hash that was generated for the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with something like this

```
SELECT  u.displayname OpponentsName,
        gsYours.score MyScore,
        gs.score OpponenetsSCore
FROM    gamescores gs INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  gs.gid,
                    gs.uid,
                    gs.score
            FROM    gamescores gs 
            where   gs.uid = yourUserID
        ) gsYours   ON  gs.gid = gsYours.gid
                    AND gs.uid <> gsYours.uid INNER JOIN
        users u ON gs.uid = u.uid INNER JOIN
              gamehistories gh ON gs.gid = gh.gid AND gh.pubID = whatYouRequireHere
```

Not really sure how you wish to link to the *gamehistories* table.

Comment: Column 'uid' in where clause is ambiguous?

Comment: I fixed that, sorry. You can have a look again.

Comment: Thanks. Still not working though: Duplicate column name 'uid'

Comment: Ah.. I was looking to pull the duration from gamehistories.. basically end-start/100 or something

Comment: How would I tack on another join to this to get at start and end from gamehistories?

Comment: That's great. I really appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select h.* from gamehistories as h join gamescores as g on g.gid=h.gid join users as u on g.uid=u.uid where u.uid=$uid
```

Right off the top of my head, dunno if there is any special sql magic that I am not using, but I typically use joins for this.

I dont see anything glaringly bad about your tables, but you do need a gamescore id field, just for the auto incrementing unique id if nothing else.  Its my policy to give every table an id, but thats just me.

Comment: Your query has some glaring deficiencies.  You're only retrieving a single score - you need to join against `gamescores` twice in order to retrieve both the opponent's score and the user's score.  And by selecting `h.*`, you're only satisfying the `duration` field in the output requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, armed with the fact that two players participate in each game, I suggest consolidating the `gamehistories` table with the `gamescores` table:

- **users** uid, displayname, email
- **games** gid, pubID, start, end, uid1, score1, uid2, score2

This results in fewer joins required to retrieve the information you want, but adds one nuance - you don't know if your user id will be in the `uid1` or `uid2` column, so you have to query both.

```
SELECT users.displayname AS `Opponent Name`,
    score1 AS `Your Score`,
    score2.score AS `Opponent Score`,
    TIMEDIFF(end, start) AS `Duration`
FROM
    users INNER JOIN games ON users.uid = games.uid1
WHERE games.gid = (TheGID)
    AND games.uid2 = (YourUID)
UNION
SELECT users.displayname AS `Opponent Name`,
    score2 AS `Your Score`,
    score1.score AS `Opponent Score`,
    TIMEDIFF(end, start) AS `Duration`
FROM
    users INNER JOIN games ON users.uid = games.uid2
WHERE games.gid = (TheGID)
    AND games.uid1 = (YourUID)
```